# NavigationPage Title to the Centre in Android (Like iOS) - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

While developing Cross Platform App through Xamarin Forms.
I am facing issue while bringing NavigationPage Title to the Centre in Android. By Default It has Aligned Left side in Android and Centre in iOS.

I would need the Android NavigationPage Title to the Centre.

Comment: please post some code that  you are using

Comment: In xf i dont think that there is a solution if there is i want it too.. you should use customrenderer..